# Oracle sql query for who speak two languages and all the countries and sum of the remaining columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database query `select * from student;`

student table having below data.

```
language     countries      know    dontknow    members
--------      -------        ----    -------    --------
english          USA        50000   20000       500000
french         FRANCE       80000   30000       800000
jerman        German        30000   40000       900000
italian        Italy        20000   50000       700000
english          USA        50000   20000       500000
french         FRANCE       80000   30000       800000
jerman        German        30000   40000       900000
italian        Italy        20000   50000       700000
```

Please provide the sql query for who speak two languages and all the countries and sum of the remaining columns.

Comment: Study more about "query".

Answer (score 0):

```
select country,
       sum(know) as know,
       sum(dontknow) as dontknow,
       sum(members) as members
from student
group by country
```